# Prestashop 1.5. Currency sign in blockspecials module

Tags: prestashop

I am using blockspecials module and there is currency shown as you can see in a picture. As long as I know, if you remove currency sign from here, you remove it from everywhere in a shop. Maybe there is a way to remove it just from the blockspecials? It doesn't look good this way.

[image]

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This module is calling a custom prestashop smarty function named displayWtPrice (located in /classes/Tools.php).  This function correctly formats a number into currency.  If you don't want this formatting, remove the smarty function from within the blockspecials.tpl.

By default it looks like ;

```
{if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
    <span class="price-discount">{if !$priceDisplay}{displayWtPrice p=$special.price_without_reduction}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$priceWithoutReduction_tax_excl}{/if}</span>
    <span class="price">{if !$priceDisplay}{displayWtPrice p=$special.price}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$special.price_tax_exc}{/if}</span>
{/if}
```

Remove the smarty tags.

```
{if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
    <span class="price-discount">{if !$priceDisplay}{$special.price_without_reduction}{else}{$priceWithoutReduction_tax_excl}{/if}</span>
    <span class="price">{if !$priceDisplay}{$special.price}{else}{$special.price_tax_exc}{/if}</span>
{/if}
```

This will leave you with an unformatted number.

If you require formatting but without the symbol and for it to be specific to just this one function, you are going to have to modify the core of prestashop.

You would have to duplicate the displayPrice function in /classes/Tools.php by overriding/extend Tools.php - create new class /overrides/classes/Tools.php

```
<?php

/**
* Tools
*/
class Tools extends ToolsCore
{

    /**
    * Return price with currency sign for a given product
    *
    * @param float $price Product price
    * @param object $currency Current currency (object, id_currency, NULL => context currency)
    * @return string Price correctly formated (sign, decimal separator...)
    */
    public static function displayPrice($price, $currency = null, $no_utf8 = false, Context $context = null, $showSymbol = true)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($price))
            return $price;
        if (!$context)
            $context = Context::getContext();
        if ($currency === null)
            $currency = $context->currency;
        // if you modified this function, don't forget to modify the Javascript function formatCurrency (in tools.js)
        elseif (is_int($currency))
            $currency = Currency::getCurrencyInstance((int)$currency);

        if (is_array($currency))
        {
            $c_char = $currency['sign'];
            $c_format = $currency['format'];
            $c_decimals = (int)$currency['decimals'] * _PS_PRICE_DISPLAY_PRECISION_;
            $c_blank = $currency['blank'];
        }
        elseif (is_object($currency))
        {
            $c_char = $currency->sign;
            $c_format = $currency->format;
            $c_decimals = (int)$currency->decimals * _PS_PRICE_DISPLAY_PRECISION_;
            $c_blank = $currency->blank;
        }
        else
            return false;

        $blank = ($c_blank ? ' ' : '');
        $ret = 0;
        if (($is_negative = ($price < 0)))
            $price *= -1;
        $price = Tools::ps_round($price, $c_decimals);
        switch ($c_format)
        {
            /* X 0,000.00 */
            case 1:
                $ret = (($showSymbol) ? $c_char : '').$blank.number_format($price, $c_decimals, '.', ',');
                break;
            /* 0 000,00 X*/
            case 2:
                $ret = number_format($price, $c_decimals, ',', ' ').$blank.(($showSymbol) ? $c_char : '');
                break;
            /* X 0.000,00 */
            case 3:
                $ret = (($showSymbol) ? $c_char : '').$blank.number_format($price, $c_decimals, ',', '.');
                break;
            /* 0,000.00 X */
            case 4:
                $ret = number_format($price, $c_decimals, '.', ',').$blank.(($showSymbol) ? $c_char : '');
                break;
            /* 0 000.00 X  Added for the switzerland currency */
            case 5:
                $ret = number_format($price, $c_decimals, '.', ' ').$blank.(($showSymbol) ? $c_char : '');
                break;
        }
        if ($is_negative)
            $ret = '-'.$ret;
        if ($no_utf8)
            return str_replace('€', chr(128), $ret);
        return $ret;
    }



}
```

Now you need to override in the same way we have done with Tools but this time the function `displayWtPrice` in the Product class.

We would override this function to like below;

```
public static function displayWtPrice($params, &$smarty)
    {
        return Tools::displayPrice($params['p'], Context::getContext()->currency, false, null, (($params['showsymbol'] == false) ? false : true));
    }
```

We have specified the additional function parameter which will be taken from smarty if provided.

Now you need to modify your `blockspecials.tpl` with the additional param in `displayWtPrice` with `showsymbol=false`

```
{if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
    <span class="price-discount">{if !$priceDisplay}{displayWtPrice p=$special.price_without_reduction showsymbol=false}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$priceWithoutReduction_tax_excl showsymbol=false}{/if}</span>
    <span class="price">{if !$priceDisplay}{displayWtPrice p=$special.price showsymbol=false}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$special.price_tax_exc showsymbol=false}{/if}</span>
{/if}
```